# How to put some notes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is there any way in Xcode to put some notes.

For example I want to work on some feature later, but want to put there a note. So that I can find all the notes I have written and go directly to the portion of code I had to work.

I have used pragma marks but it is related to a single class, I cannot know all the notes though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use below command:-

```
//TODO: some thing here
```

OR

```
#warning this will create a compiler warning.
```

And when you build the app you will get a compiler warning (a yellow triangle, not a compiler error) which is  about reminding you of things you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, can I get to know as a whole at some place in Xcode the list of all todos instead of going into each class?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with Objective-C (I'm not sure if it supports Swift yet), you can try [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/). It has built-in support for displaying all `//TODO`'s inside all of your classes.

Or you can try this [XCode plugin](https://github.com/trawor/XToDo).

Comment: Thanks, the plugin works like charm!

Answer (score -2):

If you want something like this

[image]

You can add custom bush script before or after building, running, testing,  archiving and so on!

**Steps:**

**1.** Navigate to your project's build phases in Xcode, click on the + sign towards the top left of the window, and then click on "New Run Script Build Phase" in the drop down menu:
[image]

**2.** 
You should then see a new section added where you can inject your bash script. 
In the body of your run script build phase, copy and paste this lovely bit of code:

```bash
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

**3.**
From here on out, you should now see warnings when you mark your code with TODO: or FIXME: comment blocks! Here's a screenshot:

[image]

For more details see this article by [krakendev.io](http://krakendev.io/blog/generating-warnings-in-xcode)